# RMySQL: Why is dbColumnInfo() so expensive?

Tags: r, rmysql

A call to `dbColumnInfo` takes > 5 min for a table, and a substantial amount of traffic (~ 35 mbps). The table *is* big:

```
> dbGetQuery(connRemoteDB, statement = "select count(*) from bidders")
  count(*)
1 77850272
```

but since `dbColumnInfo` does not return anything that depends on the size of the table, I don't see why it would take this long?

```
> dbColumnInfo(connRemoteDB, "bidders")                                          
name    Sclass       type length
1      daynum   integer    INTEGER     11
2  account_id character VAR_STRING     40
3        rank   integer    INTEGER     11
4   keyphrase character VAR_STRING    500
5     avg_bid    double     DOUBLE     22
6 impressions    double     DOUBLE     22
7      clicks    double     DOUBLE     22
```

Comment: Is it still so slow in the dev version (from github)?